# How come W3TC is allowed to host premium code in the WordPress repo?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, licensing, plugin-repository

I have noticed W3TC is allowed to host premium code in the WordPress Repo.

You may download their plugin freely from the WordPress repo, but certain features are paid, and you need a license key before you can leverage these features.

In their settings page, they have a "license" field, and when entered, premium features are unlocked.

I was under the impression that this is not allowed according to WordPress guidelines, and you need to seperate paid/premium code from the free code, in the WordPress Plugin Repo, as they do not allow hosting of this.

Please enlighten me.

[image: icen]

Comment: You’re not allowed to require a key for code in the plugin to run, but you can require an API key or license or account or something for access to external services. It could be that, but why are you asking here? Ask them, or the WordPress plugins team. Policies for specific repos are off topic here.

Comment: @JacobPeattie they require a license for code to run, not external services

Comment: In that case take it up with the plugin review team, or ask for clarification of what's permitted: plugins@wordpress.org